# Arquivo não encontrado ao dar submit

Tags: html, formulário, upload

Tenho um formulário HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="script/overlay-div/css/overlay-div.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="script/jquery-file-upload/css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css">
<h4>Casos 1</h4>
<h5>Inserir novo caso</h5>
<div>
    <div class="form">
        <form action="http://alexandrecoluna.com/includes/casos.lib.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="nome">Nome do Caso</label>
            <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome">

            <label for="descricao">Descrição</label>
            <textarea name="descricao" class="ckeditor"></textarea>

            <label for="link">Imagem de capa</label>
            <span class="file fileinput-button">
                <span>Selecione uma foto de capa</span>
                <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="imagem">
            </span>

            <label for="link">Imagens</label>
            <span class="file fileinput-button">
                <span>Selecione as fotos para o caso</span>
                <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="imagens[]" multiple>
            </span>
            <div class="progress" style="display: none;">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="img-preview"></div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>

            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="INSERT">
            <input type="submit" value="Salvar">
            <input type="reset" value="Limpar">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    CKEDITOR.replace( 'descricao', {
        toolbar :
        [
            { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic' ] },
            { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList' ] }
        ]
    });


});
</script>
```

Após clicar no botão **Salvar** ele deveria redirecionar para a URL que está no `action`, só que quando clica ele da um tempo pequeno carregando e recebo a mensagem

> **ARQUIVO NÃO ENCONTRADO**
>
> O Firefox não conseguiu localizar o arquivo
>   http://alexandrecoluna.com/includes/casos.lib.php.
>
> Verifique se o nome do arquivo possui erros de digitação, como uma letra maiúscula em vez de minúscula.
>   Verifique se o arquivo foi movido, renomeado ou excluído.

O mais estranho é que isso só acontece caso eu seleciono várias imagens através do campo **"Imagens"** onde eu posso selecionar e enviar várias imagens. Caso eu não coloque nenhuma imagem nesse campo ele cadastra normal.

**casos.lib.php**

```
<?php

    include('class/Caso.class.php');

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        $action = ($_POST['action'] != '') ? $_POST['action'] : '' ;

        switch ($action) {
            case 'INSERT':

                $caso = new Caso($_POST['nome'], $_POST['descricao'], $_FILES['imagem'], NULL, $_FILES['imagens']);
                $response = $caso->save();

                if ($response === true) {
                    echo '<script>alert("Cadastrado com sucesso");history.go(-1);</script>';
                }
                else {
                    echo json_encode(array ( 'status' => 'error', 'desc' => $response, 'fields' => array ($caso->nome, $caso->descricao, $caso->imagem, $caso->imagens)));
                }
                break;

            case 'UPDATE':
                if (!$_FILES['imagem'] && !$_FILES['imagens']) {
                    $caso = new Caso($_POST['nome'], $_POST['descricao'], false, $_POST['id'], false);
                    $response = $caso->update();
                }elseif(isset($_FILES['imagem']) && !$_FILES["imagens"]) {
                    $caso = new Caso($_POST['nome'], $_POST['descricao'], $_FILES['imagem'], $_POST['id'], false);
                    $response = $caso->update();
                }elseif(!$_FILES['imagem'] && isset($_FILES["imagens"])){
                    $caso = new Caso($_POST['nome'], $_POST['descricao'], false, $_POST['id'], $_FILES['imagens']);
                    $response = $caso->update();
                }else{
                    $caso = new Caso($_POST['nome'], $_POST['descricao'], $_FILES['imagem'], $_POST['id'], $_FILES['imagens']);
                    $response = $caso->update();
                }

                if ($response != FALSE) {
                    echo '<script>alert("Atualizado com sucesso");history.go(-1);</script>';
                } else {
                    echo json_encode(array ( 'status' => 'error', 'desc' => $response, 'fields' => array ($caso->nome, $_POST['descricao'], $caso->imagem)));
                }
                break;

            case 'DELETE':

                $caso = new Caso();
                $response = $caso->delete($_POST['id']);

                if ($response === true) {
                    echo 'true';
                } else {
                    echo $response;
                }
                break;

            default:

                break;
        }
    }

    function showCasos($qnt = NULL) {

        $db = new Connection();

        $qryStr = (isset($qnt)) ? 'SELECT * FROM acoluna_casos ORDER BY casos_id DESC LIMIT 0, ' . $qnt : 'SELECT * FROM acoluna_casos ORDER BY casos_id DESC;';
        $qry = mysql_query($qryStr);

        if ($qry) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)) {
                $casos[] = new Caso($row['casos_nome'], $row['casos_descricao'], $row['casos_imagem'], $row['casos_id'], $row['casos_imagens']);
            }

            return (isset($casos)) ? $casos : FALSE;
        }
    }

    function getCaso($id) {
        $db = new Connection();

        if (is_numeric($id)) {
            $qryStr = "SELECT * FROM acoluna_casos WHERE casos_id='$id'";
            $qry = mysql_query($qryStr);

            if (mysql_num_rows($qry) == 1) {
                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);
                return new Caso($row['casos_nome'], $row['casos_descricao'], $row['casos_imagem'], $row['casos_id'], $row['casos_imagens']);
            }
            return NULL;
        }
    }
?>
```

**Caso.class.php**

```
<?php

/*
//  Projeto:    Cadastro de dúvidas - Alexandre Coluna
//  Class:      Dúvidas
//  Descrição:  Usada para manipular as informações
//              inseridas pelo usuário.
*/
include_once('Connection.class.php');


class Caso
{
    const   DB_TABLE = 'acoluna_casos';

    private $id, $nome, $descricao, $imagem, $imagens;

    public function __construct($nome = NULL, $descricao = NULL, $imagem = NULL, $id = NULL, $imagens = NULL) {

        $this->nome = $this->encode_html($nome);
        $this->descricao = $this->encode_html($descricao);
        $this->imagem = $this->isImage($imagem);
        $this->imagens = $this->IsmultiUpload($imagens);

        if (isset($id)) {
            $this->id = $id;
        }
    }

    private function IsmultiUpload($imagem) {
        if (is_array($imagem)) {

            if (is_uploaded_file($imagem['tmp_name'][0])) {


                return $this->multiUpload($imagem);

            }
            else {
                $imagem = FALSE;
            }
        }
        return $imagem;
    }

    public function multiUpload($imagens){

        $arrayImagens = array();

        if(!empty($imagens['name'][0])){

            for($key = 0; $key <= count($imagens)-1; $key++){

                if(!is_null($imagens['name'][$key])){

                    do{
                        $fileName = $this->random(5);
                    }while(file_exists('images/'.$fileName.'.jpg'));


                    list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($_FILES['imagens']['tmp_name'][$key]);

                    $image = copy($_FILES['imagens']['tmp_name'][$key], 'images/'.$fileName.'.jpg');

                    //setup the new size of the image
                    $height = 750;
                    $width = 650;
                    //$new_height * $ratio;

                    if($width_orig > $height_orig){
                    $height = ($width/$width_orig)*$height_orig;
                    // Se altura é maior que largura, dividimos a altura determinada pela original e multiplicamos a largura pelo resultado, para manter a proporção da imagem
                    } elseif($width_orig < $height_orig) {
                    $width = ($height/$height_orig)*$width_orig;
                    } // -> fim if

                    //move the file in the new location
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagens']['tmp_name'][$key], 'images/'.$fileName.'.jpg');


                    // resample the image
                    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
                    $old_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/'.$fileName.'.jpg');
                    imagecopyresampled($new_image,$old_image,0,0,0,0,$width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

                    //output
                    imagejpeg($new_image, 'images/'.$fileName.'.jpg', 100);


                    $arrayImagens[] = $fileName.'.jpg';
                }
            }

            return json_encode($arrayImagens);

        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    ////////////////
    // Validação //
    ////////////////

    public function isLink($link) {
        $pattern = '/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/';
        return (preg_match($pattern, $link)) ? $link : FALSE;
    }

    private function isImage($imagem) {
        if (is_array($imagem)) {

            if (is_uploaded_file($imagem['tmp_name'])) {

                $dirImg = 'images/';
                (!is_dir($dirImg)) ? mkdir($dirImg) : false;

                do {
                    $fileName = $this->random(5);
                } while (file_exists($dirImg . $fileName . '.jpg'));

                $this->resizeImage($imagem, $dirImg.$fileName.'.jpg');

                $imagem = $fileName . '.jpg';
            }
            else {
                $imagem = FALSE;
            }
        }
        return $imagem;
    }

    /**
     * [validate description]
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function validate() {

        //$vars = get_class_vars(__CLASS__);
        // foreach ($vars as $row) {
        //  if ($row == FALSE) {
        //      $return .=
        //  }
        // }
        return ($this->nome != FALSE && $this->descricao != FALSE) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }

    ////////////////////////
    // Funções Genéricas //
    ////////////////////////

    /**
     * Gera um número aleatório do tamanho definido
     * @param  Int $len Tamanho do número de saída
     * @return String      Retorna em texto os números gerados.
     */
    private function random($len) {
        $array = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
        while(strlen(@$random) < $len){
            @$random = $random . $array[rand(0,9)];
        }
        return $random;
    }

    /**
     * Atalho para decodificar caracteres HTML e aspas
     * @param  String $str Texto a ser encodado
     * @return String      Texto convertido
     */
    public function encode_html($str) {
        return htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }

    /**
     * Atalho para converter caracteres HTML e aspas
     * @param  String $str Texto a ser convertido
     * @return String      Texto convertido com as opções: {ENT_QUOTES, UTF-8}
     */
    public function decode_html($str) {
        return html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }

    /**
     * Redimensionar a imagem
     * @param  [type] $image       [description]
     * @param  [type] $target_file [description]
     * @return [type]              [description]
     */
    private function resizeImage($image, $target_file) {
        // $image is the uploaded image
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image['tmp_name']);

        $image = copy($image['tmp_name'], $target_file);

        //setup the new size of the image
        $ratio = $width/$height;
        $new_height = 750;
        $new_width = 650;
        //$new_height * $ratio;


        if($width > $height){
        $new_height = ($new_width/$width)*$height;
        // Se altura é maior que largura, dividimos a altura determinada pela original e multiplicamos a largura pelo resultado, para manter a proporção da imagem
        } elseif($width < $height) {
        $new_width = ($new_height/$height)*$width;
        } // -> fim if


        //move the file in the new location
        move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $target_file);

        // resample the image
        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
        $old_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($target_file);
        imagecopyresampled($new_image,$old_image,0,0,0,0,$new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

        //output
        imagejpeg($new_image, $target_file, 100);
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Funções para manipulação dos dados persistentes //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * Salva os dados no banco de dados
     * @return Bool/String Retorna TRUE em caso de sucesso ou a mensagem do erro em caso de erro
     */
    public function save() {
        $response = $this->validate();
        if ($response) {
            $db = new Connection();
            $qryStr = "INSERT INTO ".self::DB_TABLE." VALUES ('', '".$this->nome."', '".$this->descricao."', '".$this->imagem."', '".$this->imagens."')";
            return (mysql_query($qryStr)) ? TRUE : 'Erro ao inserir mídia no banco de dados.';
        }
        return 'Erro na validação dos dados: <br>' . $response . '<br>' . $this->nome . ' <br> ' . $this->descricao;
    }

    /**
     * Atualiza os dados de do objeto no banco de dados
     * @return Bool/String Returna TRUE em caso de sucesso ou a mensagem do erro em caso de falha
     */
    public function update() {

        if ($this->validate()) {
            $db = new Connection();
            if ($this->imagem != false && $this->imagens == false) { //Se existir foto de capa e não existir imagens
                $qryStr = 'UPDATE ' . self::DB_TABLE . ' SET casos_nome="' . $this->nome . '", casos_descricao="' . $this->descricao . '", casos_imagem="' . $this->imagem . '" WHERE casos_id=' . $this->id . ';';
                $i = 1;
            } elseif($this->imagem == false && $this->imagens == false) { //Se não existir nem foto de capa nem imagens
                $qryStr = 'UPDATE ' . self::DB_TABLE . ' SET casos_nome="' . $this->nome . '", casos_descricao="' . $this->descricao . '" WHERE casos_id=' . $this->id . ';';
                $i = 2;
            }elseif($this->imagem == false && $this->imagens != false){ //Se não existir foto de capa mas existir imagens
                $qryStr = "UPDATE " . self::DB_TABLE . " SET casos_nome='" . $this->nome . "', casos_descricao='" . $this->descricao . "', casos_imagens='" . $this->imagens . "' WHERE casos_id=" . $this->id . ";";
                $i = 3;
            }elseif($this->imagem != false && $this->imagens != false){ //Se existir foto de capa e imagens
                $qryStr = "UPDATE " . self::DB_TABLE . " SET casos_nome='" . $this->nome . "', casos_descricao='" . $this->descricao . "', casos_imagem='" . $this->imagem . "', casos_imagens='".$this->imagens."' WHERE casos_id=" . $this->id . ";";
                $i = 4;
            }
            return mysql_query($qryStr) ? TRUE : FALSE;
        }
        return 'Erro na validação dos dados';
    }

    /**
     * Exclui permanentemente o objeto no banco de dados
     * @param  Int $id Número do registro do objeto no banco de dados
     * @return Bool/String     Retorna TRUE em caso de sucesso ou a mensagem do erro em caso de falha
     */
    public function delete($id) {
        if (isset($id)) {
            $db = new Connection();
            $searchQry = 'SELECT * FROM ' . self::DB_TABLE . ' WHERE casos_id="' . $id . '";';
            $qry = mysql_query($searchQry);

            if (mysql_num_rows($qry) != 1) {
                return 'Dúvida não encontrado no banco de dados.';
            }

            $qryStr = 'DELETE FROM ' . self::DB_TABLE . ' WHERE casos_id="' . $id . '";';
            return mysql_query($qryStr) ? TRUE : 'Erro ao excluir dúvida. Por favor, tente novamente mais tarde.';
        }
        return 'ID de dúvida inválido.';
    }

    //////////////////////
    // Métodos Mágicos //
    //////////////////////

    /**
     * Em caso de String, decodifica e retorna a variável
     * @param  String $var Texto a ser convertido
     * @return String      Em caso de String, retorna a variável decodificada
     */
    public function __get($var) {
        if (property_exists($this, $var)) {
            return (is_string($this->$var)) ? $this->decode_html($this->$var) : $this->$var;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Você ta usando uma biblioteca jQuery para enviar arquivos ao servidor ? Coloque parte do código para que pessoas consigam te ajudar, o HTML em si aparente não ter problema.

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes Não estou usando jQuery para enviar arquivos. Somente HTML e PHP

Comment: No PHP, você usa o `$_FILES` ? Estranho ele não encontrar o arquivo quando você insere uma imagem e encontrar quando não colocar, deveria dar algum outro erro ao invés deste... Certifique-se ao inserir a imagem não há nada que altere a action do form...

Comment: Sim, uso `$_FILES` . O estranho é que no campo **Foto de Capa** que é uma só, se eu escolho uma foto e dou **Salvar** sem escolher as fotos da postagem (que seria essa de escolher multiplas fotos) ele vai certinho. Agora se coloco 1 imagem ou mais na fotos da postagem ele já da esse pau.

Comment: Seria interessante vc postar o PHP, o HTML aparentemente está ok.

Comment: @Diego Adicionado

Comment: Os dois `<input type="file">` estão compartilhando o mesmo `id`, isso pode estar afetando a lógica do `submit`